# How to implement multiple select in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wonder how to implement multiple select in MVC 
As was demonstrated in this [doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075803/how-to-implement-multiple-select-in-mvc-3-using-chosen-js-plugin), but the only difference is that my information is populated via jquery

```
function (dataResult) {
    var select = $("#dataLeT");

    $.each(dataResult, function (index, itemData) {
        select.append($('<option/>', {
            value: itemData.Value,
            text: itemData.Text
        }));
    });
});
```

I tried some ways, but could not. is only in this way

[image]

How can I leave the same way of example.

Comment: Where you are facing problem whether in populating `options` or in `chosen plugin`?

Comment: Kendo UI Web has a decent javascript multiselect widget. It works kind of like the tag selection control here on SO.

Comment: I'm having trouble letting em in the format of the example.